# Updating the value of one variable updates the value of another

Tags: python

```
spam = "woo"
eggs = spam
spam = "string"
print eggs
# prints woo
```

However for array, it is different:

```
import numpy
# The coefficients for the Taylor polynomial for exp(x)
Taylor_coefficients = numpy.array(
[1.0, 0.5, 0.1666, 0.04164, 0.0083, 0.0014])
coeff = Taylor_coefficients
coeff[1] = 0
print Taylor_coefficients[:2]
# prints [ 1.  0.]
```

What happens here, and which other common datatypes than array does this apply to?

Comment: This has (almost) nothing to do with strings versus arrays. It has to do with plain assignment versus item assignment (`a[b] = c`).

Comment: (The possible duplicate speaks of function arguments, but assignment behaves exactly the same way.)

Answer (score -1):

This difference in behavior is due to the difference between mutable and immutable objects. Read the [wiki page](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Data_Types) for more information on python types.

When you `spam = "string"`, spam is pointed to a new location with a new string, because strings are immutable (cannot be changed after creation), which leaves `eggs` in-tact, pointing to the old string. But for arrays (or other mutable objects), `coff = Taylor_coefficients` will point to the same object, and changing that object will reflect in all references to it.